jQuery Regex validation query
I'm currently using the following regex, which works as needed.
^[0-9*#.?-&\s]+$

However I also need this to allow a single word as well. The word may appear by itself, or with any of the other valid characters, or it may not appear at all.
eg:
^[0-9*#.?-&**PASS**\s]+$

But as I've added it above that will match on the individual letters P,A,S,S not PASS.
How do I do that ?
examples of what need to work:
123
*123
?123
#123
*123*
*123*
123*
*pass
pass*
**pass
pass**

I may need to add FAIL to the same check - is that possible ?
Thanks

@user24714692 post updated.

@user24714692 yes

Sorry yes, just lowercase.

Try: ^[0-9*#.?&\s-]*(?:pass|fail)?[0-9*#.?&\s-]*$. You want - literally. Right? such as, 123-pass-* is allowed?

yes they are allows as words by themselves.

Does this work ^[0-9*#.?&\s-]*(?:pass|fail)?[0-9*#.?&\s-]*$ for all your samples?

That does appear to work. Do you want to create this as an answer ?

If you want pass and fail to be allowed within:
^[0-9*#.?&\s-]*(?:pass|fail)?[0-9*#.?&\s-]*$

Note:
- is a metachar for ranges, and if you want it literally, you should put it at the end or start of [].
